# Caching in an asynchronous service

Tags: wcf, caching, asynchronous

So, I've run into an interesting situation.  Let's say I have a rarely-changing set of data, so I don't want to get it on every call to a high-volume service.  I will typically cache this data for a period of time (depending on how rarely changing it really is).  This is pretty straightforward:

```
private T GetOrSet<T>(string key, Func<T> getToSet, int minutes, object lockObject)
{
    T value = (T)HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(key);
    if (value == null)
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            value = (T)HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(key);
            if (value == null)
            {
                value = getToSet();
                HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(key, value, null, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(minutes), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
            }
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

If the `getToSet` function fails, I never Insert, so it gets attempted again on the next call.

However, if I use this same pattern in an asynchronous service, the `getToSet` function returns a `Task<>` - and now I've cached a `Task` that returns a failed result for a period of time.  Assuming that the time to call `getToSet` is not negligible, how do I prevent caching a failed result while still not blocking a thread during the data retrieval?

Short but complete example below; this will cache a failed result for one minute, during which time every call to `GetData` will fail, and then the service will start returning `5` for every call.

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Caching;

namespace TaskCacheIssue
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Task<int> GetData();
    }

    public class Service1 : IService1
    {

        public async Task<int> GetData()
        {
            return await GetDataFromCache();
        }

        private static bool first = true;
        private static readonly object deadbolt = new object();
        private async Task<int> GetDataFromCache()
        {
            return await GetOrSet(
                "key",
                async () => await GetDataFromSomewhereElse(),
                1,
                deadbolt);
        }

        private async Task<int> GetDataFromSomewhereElse()
        {
            // This is actually a longer-running data retrieval.
            if (first)
            {
                first = false;
                throw new Exception("FIRST!");
            }
            return 5;
        }

        private T GetOrSet<T>(string key, Func<T> getToSet, int minutes, object lockObject)
        {
            T value = (T)HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(key);
            if (value == null)
            {
                lock (lockObject)
                {
                    value = (T)HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(key);
                    if (value == null)
                    {
                        value = getToSet();
                        HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(key, value, null, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(minutes), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
                    }
                }
            }
            return value;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of exclusively evaluating for null, additionally check if the cached value is a failed task.

```
private T GetOrSet<T>(string key, Func<T> getToSet, int minutes, object lockObject)
{
    T value = (T)HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(key);
    if (value == null || IsCanceledOrFaultedTask(value))
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            value = (T)HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(key);
            if (value == null || IsCanceledOrFaultedTask(value))
            {
                value = getToSet();
                HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(key, value, null, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(minutes), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
            }
        }
    }
    return value;
}

private bool IsCanceledOrFaultedTask(object target)
{
    if (target is Task)
    {
        var task = (Task)target;
        return (task.IsCanceled || task.IsFaulted);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This approach is basically fine except that it is a hack to runtime cast to task. It would be better to base GetOrSet on Task<T> in the first place.

Comment: Fair enough. OP could just create a separate method (GetOrSetTask) explicitly for dealing with Tasks, then just adjust the conditionals to: if (value == null || (value != null && (value.IsCanceled || value.IsFaulted)))

Comment: I think I like this, in combination with the overload mentioned above - it provides { centralized code, no blocking }, which I think makes sense for a highly-shared piece of code, and it lets the caller determine whether to block to get { single caller failure }.  (Basically, be optimistic in the shared code and allow the caller to figure out their own level of pessimism / requirement for error minimization.)

Answer (score 1):

When retrieving a value from the cache and awaiting it check the result. If it is failed clear the cache and insert a new value into it.

Comment: So, you're saying to await the result that comes back from `(T)HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(key)` if `T is Task`?  What if two threads call `GetToSet` at the same time?  We can't `await` inside a `lock`, so I couldn't check the result again inside the lock, and wouldn't subsequent callers just fail at the `await` in `GetToSet` anyway then?

Comment: I though about doing this "retry" work in GetDataFromCache because there you know that T is a task (in fact a Task<int>). I don't think GetOrSet needs to deal with tasks or waiting at all.

Comment: How strict are your requirements regarding duplicate execution? If that is totally forbidden then you really have to think this through. If very rare duplicate execution is allowed then any race condition you might introduce isn't fatal. That would be convenient.

Comment: The problem with putting it outside of `GetOrset` is that I want `GetOrSet` to be generally applicable so that I can call it from multiple places without repeating myself.  I think, in the ideal case, I wouldn't want to run multiple requests at the same time.  I'm not sure I can get my ideal of { single caller failure, no blocking, centralized code }.. so I want as generally applicable a solution as possible.  Which requires { centralized code }.. but which is better to give up?  Single caller failure or no blocking in the general case?

Comment: What about making GetOrSet operate on a Task<T> instead of on a T? That way this method can reason about failure. It also can start to await things. You certainly can make all this logic into a reusable method. Btw, you can make the lock async as well by using AsyncLock (on the web) or SemaphoreSlim. The benefit of doing that will be extremely low or negative since the wait time is supposed to be near zero.

Comment: So, I can add an overload of GetOrSet that works with Task<T> instead of just T. At this point, I can "await" it, which would cause the error to occur, similar to how it would in the original sample without `async`. Though, this would require changing out for the `AsyncLock` or the `SemaphoreSlim`.
I need to run to lunch, but let me look into this when I get back.